# Service Fires Hundreds Of Time On Single Broadcast

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, android-service

I am sending a broadcast from an activity to a service:

Activity:

```
        Timber.d("SENDING REQUEST");
        // Send broadcast to service to request GPS (this avoids concurrency issues with file collision)
        Intent updateActivitiesRequest = new Intent(A_GPS.UPDATE_ACTIVITIES_REQUEST);
        sendBroadcast(updateActivitiesRequest);
```

Service:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        startService(intent);

        _updateRequestReciever = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "GOT IT");
               // broadcastSavedActivityDataForToday();
            }
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(A_GPS.UPDATE_ACTIVITIES_REQUEST);
        registerReceiver(_updateRequestReciever, intentFilter);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

However, when the request is fired once, I get hundreds of fires from the `onReceive` in my service:

> D/A_GPS: SENDING REQUEST
>
> D/S_GPS: GOT IT
>
> D/S_GPS: GOT IT
>
> D/S_GPS: GOT IT
>
> D/S_GPS: GOT IT
>
> ...and hundreds more

It fires so many times in fact my logcat cant even process it and I get a range of errors flooding the console. Some of the errors I get when I tried to send my response are are:

1. Failed Transaction Binder (and !! FAILED TRANSACTION BINDER !!)
2. Failure sending broadcast result of Intent {} android.os.DeadObjectException
3. TransactionTooLargeException

Clearly this is a result of it trying to send a reply when I uncomment `broadcastSavedActivityDataForToday()` and it turns out to be hundreds of replies.

Do you have any idea why my broadcast receiver in my service is firing hundreds of times from a single broadcast intent?

Comment: I thought of this but I read another one of your posts where you said a service is a natural singleton. So shouldnt there always only be one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. Your service is calling `startService()` on itself from `onStartCommand()`. This is what we call an "infinite loop". Do not do this.
2. You are registering the receiver in `onStartCommand()`, and so will register one for every `startService()` call. Register the receiver once in `onCreate()`.

Comment: This is correct. Moving it to onCreate fixes it. I thought `startCommand` only fired once as well.

Comment: @Aggressor: It fires once per `startService()` call. Even without the infinite loop, you might wind up with more than one receiver if you called `startService()` multiple times legitimately.